# LongPressGestureRecognizer not working with TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureREcognizer`. 
In view did load I have:

```
oneTapRecognizer.delegate = self
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
oneTapRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(longPressRecognizer)
```

Then I also have function:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
    }
```

I do see that above function is being reached multiple times as i tap.
then I'm trying to act on long press with:

```
@IBAction func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    println("long pressed")
}
```

but long press doesn't work. Tap is working fine.

Comment: You don't want long press and tap recognized simultaneously. It's one or the other, but not both simultaneously.

Comment: Is your tap gesture recognizer working? If you remove it, does the long press now work? I'm wondering if there's just something wrong with the creation of the long press recognizer. Perhaps show the creation of the recognizers.

Comment: i had added both in IB so no extra code to show.

Comment: Still, I'd temporarily remove the tap gesture and see if the long press works at all. There's no trick to getting them to work together, so I'd first make sure the long press works at all.